# Retrieving Data from Firebase, Mapping to Element in ArrayList, and Sorting

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an ArrayList that represents different teams in a game, and they have different scores. In Firebase, I have assigned each team a point value. I don't know how to get this point value data back in Android Studio so that I can sort the ArrayList.

So far I have tried using Comparable but I haven't gotten anywhere with that. I wanted to use a TreeMap but I think an ArrayList works best for the situation.

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        u1 = database.getReference("Hawkeyes");
        u2 = database.getReference("Lions");
        u3 = database.getReference("Tigers");
        sportTeams = new ArrayList<String>();

        sportTeams.add("Hawkeyes");
        sportTeams.add("Lions");
        sportTeams.add("Tigers");
```

In firebase, it looks like this:

Hawkeyes - "20"

Lions - "64"

Tigers - "25"

I want to be able to retrieve the data in a way so that I can sort the ArrayList based on these point values. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your question as being so: "How do I read in data from Firebase and sort the data"

Rather than storing your data in the manner you are right now, you may want to store it like this (this is how arrays are typically stored in Firebase)

- Random UID

  - Team Name
  - Team Score
- Random UID

  - Team Name
  - Team Score

and so on....

you can generate these UIDs with this method:

```
.push().getKey()
```

on any DatabaseReference.

To answer your question, you could do so with this (from Firebase documentation):

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    System.out.println(post);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

The value of "dataSnapshot" will be whatever your DatabaseReference object contains as a Snapshot. You can access these values as objects with the .getValue(ClassName.class) method. So, if your Team object has a "name" property and a "score" property, you would fetch these values as a Team object from Firebase.

Now, to sort these values, you can use any sort algorithm to organize these teams (alphabetically, or score based). For instance, you can use a quick sort or an insertion sort.

More info on sorts here:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjO94DHm6bhAhUMP6wKHYQZCfMQwqsBMAF6BAgIEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPgBzjlCcFvc&usg=AOvVaw2R-qjBfc9H9YEivdMxn7r_

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-o8y7m6bhAhUqgK0KHbtKBIQQwqsBMBF6BAgLEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOGzPmgsI-pQ&usg=AOvVaw0ExA52VpJJrxjnxfruRhy4

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Collections.sort(your_arrayList);
Collections.reverse(your_arrayList);
```

To sort the numbers of the teams, first, get them and then apply this, or just use a [comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) with your object data.